# Customize register FOSUserBundle with Bootstrap

Tags: symfony, twitter-bootstrap, fosuserbundle

I create a Form builder.php like in bootstrap documentation to build my login form and my register form, like that : http://bootstrap.braincrafted.com/base-css#forms
But next I discover the FOSUserBundle and I think it's maybe a good idea to use it.
The problem is : I can't simply reuse the forms created before.

I want to use bootstrap to customize FOSUser template.
Especially for the submit buttons, I want to add for all of them : class="btn primary large"

I create a UserBundle which override the FOSUserBundle.

I customize the login.html.twig in FOSUserBundle, putting a login.html.twig in UserBundle/Ressources/Views/Security/login.html.twig

It's easy because there is only one file for the login template.

But how I can do it for registration part for example ?

There is two files : register.html.twig and register_content.html.twig

So I create a Registration folder in my UserBundle, and I put in these two files.

But, what did I put into to change the style of the submit button ?

In register.html.twig I let :

```
{% extends "UserBundle::layout.html.twig" %}

{% block fos_user_content %}
{% include "UserBundle:Registration:register_content.html.twig" %}
{% endblock fos_user_content %}
```

And in register_content.html.twig :

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_registration_register') }}" {{ form_enctype(form) }} method="POST" class="fos_user_registration_register">
    {{ form_widget(form) }}
    <div>
        <input class="btn primary large" type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans({}, 'FOSUserBundle') }}" />
    </div>
</form>
```

But it's don't work.

Did you think it's a good solution to use that bundle ?
https://github.com/CCETC/FOSUserBundle

It integrate directly all the form with bootstrap style.

But if one day I want to add a field in registration form (like gender for example), could I do it in this bundle, like with the original FOSUserBundle ?

Knowing that I want to add some custom fields in register form, and customize forms with bootstrap, I'm wondering if it's a good idea to use FOSUserBundle or if it's better to build a fresh new bundle of my own to manage the user on my website.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to add custom fields in the register form, you have to override the form :

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_forms.md

Add fields to your User entity and in the buildForm method, simply add your custom fields

```
 $builder->add('name');
```

Comment: Yes I know that, but is that a good choice to take FOSUserBundle if I have to add some personnal field, and override all the template looks with bootstrap ?
And then, How can I customize the register template ? It's more complicated than login template...

Thx !

Comment: I think FOSUserBundle is the better choice :) you will spend a little time to customize layouts and forms but you'll win a lot of time for others things..
for the register template you have to remove
`{{ form_widget(form) }}` to decompose for each fields like this :

`{{ form_widget(form.email) }}`

Answer (score 7):

This is a complete example of how I do it (boostrap mode :P, you can adapte to simple html or others frames). You have to look at the end of the form and you pay attention in the "**{{ form_rest(form) }}**" this is the code how symfony it draw de token

```
<!-- BEGIN REGISTRATION FORM -->
{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register'}}) }}
    <h3 class="font-green">Register Form</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.username, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control placeholder-no-fix', 'placeholder':'User Name'} }) }}
        {% for errorItem in form.username.vars.errors %}
        <span class="help-inline">{{ errorItem.message }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.email, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'E-mail'} }) }}
        {% for errorItem in form.email.vars.errors %}
        <span class="help-inline">{{ errorItem.message }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.first, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Password'} }) }}
        {% for errorItem in form.plainPassword.first.vars.errors %}
        <span class="help-inline">{{ errorItem.message }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ form_widget(form.plainPassword.second, { 'attr': {'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder':'Repeat Password'} }) }}
        {% for errorItem in form.plainPassword.second.vars.errors %}
        <span class="help-inline">{{ errorItem.message }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
        <a class="btn btn-default" href="{{ path('fos_user_security_login') }}">Back to login</a>
        <button type="submit" id="register-submit-btn" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
    </div>
    {{ form_rest(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
<!-- END REGISTRATION FORM -->
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in your title: you have FOSUserBundle and you want Bootstrap CSS to style it. You can style it all yourself like in Carlos Garcia's answer, or apply a sitewide theme in Symfony3.

```
# app/config/config.yml
# Twig Configuration
twig:
  form_themes: ['bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig']
```

This applies the Twig theme at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form/bootstrap_3_layout.html.twig which adds a `class="form-control"` to all text fields so Bootstrap CSS will style it, amongst other stuff.

But that theme only styles `<button>` and not the `<input type="submit"` that FOSUserBundle seems to use for some reason. So you still need to override the FOSUserBundle register_content.html.twig and the `btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block` class manually.

```
# app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views/Registration/register_content.html.twig
{% trans_default_domain 'FOSUserBundle' %}

{{ form_start(form, {'method': 'post', 'action': path('fos_user_registration_register'), 'attr': {'class': 'fos_user_registration_register'}}) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
<div>
    <input class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="{{ 'registration.submit'|trans }}" />
</div>
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

Answer (score -6):

modifie FOSUB layout file in "vendor/fos../resource/views/" (or overwrite) ex:

```
{% extends 'JamBlogBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="span9">
        <section id="erreurs">
        {% for type, messages in app.session.flashbag.all() %}
            {% for message in messages %}
                <div class="flash-{{ type }}">
                    {{ message }}
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
        </section>
        <section id="foscontent">
        {% block fos_user_content %}
        {% endblock fos_user_content %}
        </section>
    </div>
etc....
```

and the "JamBlogBundle:layout.html.twig"

```
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %} /** with bootstrap.css **/
{% block title %} {{ parent() }} - Le Blog {% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class="jumbotron subhead">
<div class="container">
    <h1>Le blog de Jamonce !</h1>
    <p class="lead">Lire, écrire, écouter et partager notre passion de la musique.</p>
</div>
</div>
{% block content %} {% endblock %}
<footer class="footer">
<div class="container">
etc.....
```

for the custom fields, See the reponse above. 
If it can help

Comment: You should never modify framework or external bundles directly

Comment: There's a way to overwrite bundle views